# What's new in Hibernate 4?

Tags: java, hibernate, changelog

I just saw that a beta of Hibernate 4 was released. What's new in 4 compared to 3(.6)? I couldn't find this info in the beta announcement, nor when Googling the title of this question.

Comment: You mean this? https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH/fixforversion/11242

Comment: @prusswan: No, that's just some fixed bugs/closed tickets in this specific release. I'm looking for a prose version of the large-scale changes/improvement between 3 and 4 (i.e. the reasons they made it 4 and not 3.7)

Comment: Oopps sorry I posted the same answer which what you don't need.

Comment: Be careful that the old "caching model" has been removed from the API :)

Comment: [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11499929/api-or-code-difference-between-hibernate-3-and-4 It would be helpful if someone from hibernate community gives answer to this link also.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

I can't paste the answers here because I don't have enough reputation points to add more than two links in the answer (I really need spend more time on this site) :(

So, I wrote a [blog post](http://in.relation.to/Bloggers/WhatsNewInHibernateCore40). Please go there and find the answers. Sorry for the inconvenience.

---

EDIT: Quoted from http://in.relation.to/Bloggers/WhatsNewInHibernateCore40.

> ## What's new in Hibernate Core 4.0
>
> I saw someone is asking "what new in Hibernate Core 4.0", so I take
>   sometime and try to summary it here. first of all, please see:
>
> - The migration [guide for 4.0](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/HibernateCoreMigrationGuide40)
> - JIRA [filter](https://hibernate.onjira.com/secure/IssueNavigator.jspa?mode=hide&requestId=11567) link which lists all *improvements- and *new features* in *Hibernate Core 4.0.0*, you can get all details from this link :)
>
> Some highlights:
>
> - Move to [gradle](http://www.gradle.org/) for builds
> - Redesign SessionFactory building
> - Introduction of services (see [this](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/hibernate/index.php?title=Category:Services) for more details)
> - Improved metamodel (not in 4.0.0.Final yet, we planned this, but due to the tasks are more than we expected, and it would take too long
>     to get 4.0 out, so we decided to move this out of 4.0.0.Final but will
>     be upcoming release soon see [this](http://in.relation.to/Bloggers/HibernateCore400CR1Release) for more details, and [this](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/hibernate/index.php?title=Category:Metamodel) is a
>     design document)
> - Initial osgi-fication by package splitting (public, internal, spi)
> - Support for multi-tenant databases (see [this](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/Multi-tenancyDesign) for more details)
> - Migration to i18n logging framework (using [jboss logging](https://github.com/jbossas/jboss-logging))
> - JDK 1.6 (JDBC4) as baseline
> - and more (I can't remember all the things :)

Comment: I have added the useful information from the blog. Does the updated answer match your blog post concept?

Comment: I hope something will be done about the mapping for SQL Server BigInts :P

Answer (score 15):

It appears that most of what you want are in the [migration guide for 4.0](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/HibernateCoreMigrationGuide40), as well as the [blog post on alpha 1 release](http://in.relation.to/Bloggers/HibernateCore400Alpha1Released), and perhaps the [Hibernate 4 webinar](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/Hibernate4Webinar).

Comment: Doesn't look like there are any exciting things (at least not for me who develops simple applications with JPA)

Answer (score 6):

New features that are introduced in Hibernate core 4.0 releases are as follows:

- Provide support for initial multi-tenancy
- Introduces a ServiceRegistry.
- Clean up of Session opening from SessionFactory.
- Using org.hibernate.integrator.spi.Integrator made integration and auto discovery more desirable.
- Improve to work with i18n and message codes.
- Clean up of deprecated interfaces, methods, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Don't know if this will benefit you, but I found *some* information on the [Hibernate 4 Webinar](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/Hibernate4Webinar#jive-body) page. In a linked doc they also gave some links. I have not had a look at them, but maybe give them a go:

http://community.jboss.org/wiki/Hibernate4Webinar

http://community.jboss.org/wiki/HibernateCoreMigrationGuide40

https://lists.jboss.org/mailman/listinfo/hibernate-dev

http://www.hibernate.org/community/irc