# API or code : Difference between Hibernate 3 and 4?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have pasted **Hibernate 3** configuration file , SessionFactory class to configure this config.xml and a bean with JPA annotations. I want to know if I were using **Hibernate 4** then what would have been the changes in the context at code level or very broad differences or advancements in layman language.

> hibernate.cfg.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.2.144:1521:xe</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">prateek</property>
        <property name="connection.password">prateek</property>
        <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
        <mapping class="com.vaannila.domain.User1" />
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

> Static java class to establish connection (SessionFactory Helper)

```
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class SessionFactoryHelper {
    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    static {
        try {            
            /*
             * Build a SessionFactory object from session-factory configuration 
             * defined in the hibernate.cfg.xml file. In this file we register 
             * the JDBC connection information, connection pool, the hibernate 
             * dialect that we used and the mapping to our hbm.xml file for each 
             * POJO (Plain Old Java Object).
             * 
             */
            sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            System.err.println("Error in creating SessionFactory object." 
                + e.getMessage());
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(e);
        }
    }

    /*
     * A static method for other application to get SessionFactory object 
     * initialized in this helper class.
     * 
     */
    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }
}
```

> Bean class

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="USER1")
public class User1 {

    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String gender;
    private String country;
    private String aboutYou;
    private Boolean mailingList;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="USER_ID") 
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name="USER_NAME")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Column(name="USER_GENDER")
    public String getGender() {
        return gender;
    }
    public void setGender(String gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    @Column(name="USER_COUNTRY")
    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }
    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }

    @Column(name="USER_ABOUT_YOU")
    public String getAboutYou() {
        return aboutYou;
    }
    public void setAboutYou(String aboutYou) {
        this.aboutYou = aboutYou;
    }

    @Column(name="USER_MAILING_LIST")
    public Boolean getMailingList() {
        return mailingList;
    }
    public void setMailingList(Boolean mailingList) {
        this.mailingList = mailingList;
    }

}
```

Comment: Please don't down vote its an important question I will be requiring the technology change in my project.

Comment: It's not constructive to downvote without commenting the reason behind it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### hibernate.cfg.xml

File hibernate.cfg.xml is fine. It may look confusing that version is still 3.0 in hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd, but thats how it is. DTD was not updated. Maybe you want to use names names prefixed with hibernate instead, for example `hibernate.show_sql` instead of `show_sql`. Names of properties can be found from [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/manual/en-US/html_single/#configuration-sessionfactory). Usually DTD_location used is `http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd` (vs. ..sourceforge...), but both should work.

### Building session factory

As you see from the [API](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/cfg/Configuration.html#buildSessionFactory%28%29), buildSessionFactory is deprecated. This is how it is built in 4.x:

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
conf.configure();
serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(conf.getProperties()).buildServiceRegistry();        
sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
```

In many places in documentation this is still not up to date.

### Annotating entities

In general no changes are needed to your mappings in bean class. Reason is that you are using normal JPA mappings and also Hibernate 3 is implementation of what is described in JPA specification.