# Updating from Hibernate 3.6 to Hibernate 4.0

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I want to know the key differences I need to take care of if I want to switch to *Hibernate 4.0* from *Hibernate 3.6* ? Does *Hibernate 4.0* support `hbm.xml` or do I need to use JPA for mapping?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6830501/whats-new-in-hibernate-4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hibernate 4 still supports ORM mapping via XML (hbm.xml).  As suggested by the mapping section in this [basic hibernate 4 tutorial](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.0/quickstart/en-US/html_single/#hibernate-gsg-tutorial-basic).

Comment: @Ranna glad I could help.  You may run into some small issues, but I'm guessing their not going to completely break their interface.

Answer (score 1):

You should read the migration guide
https://community.jboss.org/wiki/HibernateCoreMigrationGuide40