# Hibernate 3.x vs 4.x performance perspective

Tags: hibernate, jpa

Is there is any differences in the performance between  hibernate 3.x and 4.x ?
and what is recommended to use (i mean is hibernate 4.x is stable)

Answer (score 1):

Since Hibernate 4.x has been release a while ago (2011) it can be already seen as stable.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6830501/whats-new-in-hibernate-4) question highlights what is new/improvements about Hibernate 4 and [this](http://www.withoutbook.com/DifferenceBetweenSubjects.php?subId1=64&subId2=65&d=Difference%20between%20Hibernate%203%20and%20Hibernate%204) website makes a comparison between versions 3 and 4 presenting the improvements made in each release.